# A script on this page may be busy, or It may have stopped responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-addin, jquery-ui

there is one webpart on page that rotate the images so i added a jquery to rotate images and its working fine but after sometime it gives error like
**A script on this page may be busy, or It may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete** and then page crashes. how to avoid this problem ?

Comment: I have faced this issue. Mostly it happens when we are having custom js file that takes time to execute or in case of error which will hang the page . When do you get the message exactly ? As soon as you save the page or edit the page ? As a piece of help please do check your custom js for any errors.

Comment: What Browsers are causing the issues?

Comment: not working in any browser

Comment: did you try to run your script asynchronously ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, a webpage contains script that takes an unusually long time to run. If you are scripting an ActiveX control on a webpage to transfer a very large file or run a large database query, this often causes a significantly long delay. Internet Explorer 3.02 detects the long delay, and prompts the user with a dialog box that reads as follows:

Please find below the link  for the fix this is free from microsoft and should be installed on client's machine as this is client setting. [microsoft  kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500)

Comment: yes ,i run a infinite banner rotating